# Importing ObjectID as string

Tags: mongodb, solr, dataimporthandler, solr6

I am trying to upgrade a Solr 6.2.1 single node instance to a SolrCloud setup using the Solr version 6.6. The issue I am facing is that while performing data import from mongodb using the solr-mongo-importer-1.1.0.jar and mongo-java-driver-2.14.3.jar, the _id field is being imported as `"_id":"org.bson.types.ObjectId:585a53d109ed44343743ebd1"` instead of `"_id":"585a53d109ed44343743ebd1"` as in the Solr 6.2.1 instance. (The jars are the same version in both the cases)

The schema contains the following (same in both versions):

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"sortMissingLast="true"/>
<field name="_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Is there any change in the fieldType in the new version or am I missing something?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage%20with%20Solr Specifically this section: **Unique Keys between Solr and MongoDB**

Comment: can we have a peek at your data import handler config?

Answer (score 0):

Solr fields should be declared in schema.xml.
It is possible that id is already defined!

Alternatively, Please try setting column attribute with name -

```
<field column="_id"  name="id"/>               
<field column="OtherNumber" name="OtherNumber" mongoField="OthNumber"/>
```

OR

Try using this directive for specifying _id field

```
<uniqueKey>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, id is not already defined. Also, the uniqueKey is specified for _id field.

Comment: Did you try setting 'column' attribute along with 'name' ?